# Python code snippet that runs always when a ipython notebook closes

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to add a python code to an ipython notebook that will run every time I close the ipython tab. I tried to see if I can set a cell to do it but I had no luck.

Is this possible either using an ipython API or some other hook mechanism?

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have tried? It is very hard to verify what exactly you want or your problem is without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) python module to register an exit handler. This would work if your page in the IPython notebook is actually a python process.

Comment: Have you tried it? I believe closing the window doesn't kill the kernel.